# Upgrade from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5 with LimitChunkSizePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-5

I have an vue 2 application with webpack 4 that I wanted to upgrade to webpack 5.
I'm using the LimitChunkSizePlugin as below in my vue.config.js (configuration section of webpack is included within this file.)

```
    }
  },
  plugins : [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
  ]
};
```

This code is causing the build to fail as below :

```
.../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/comparators.js:39
                map.set(arg, result);
                    ^

TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key
    at WeakMap.set (<anonymous>)
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/comparators.js:39:7
    at .../node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/LimitChunkCountPlugin.js:79:37
    ...
```

do you have any idea about this ?
I was looking at this : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/
but there is no mention whatsoever of such problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.